# internal compiling error when using template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I am trying to migrate a project from VS2008 to VS2013,
The project compiles and works in VS2008, unfortunately I suddenly receive an "An internal error has occurred in the compiler" when compiling the same code with VS2013.
The error occurs when trying the call a method of a template class

```
void func(const CMatrix<CSegment>& segments) const
{
    int row, col;
    row = segments.NumOfRows(); //error points to here
    col = segments.NumOfColumns(); // if I remove the above line then the error points to here
}
```

and CMatrix is defined like so:

```
class CBaseMatrix
{
public:
    CBaseMatrix() {};
    virtual ~CBaseMatrix() {};
    virtual void Resize(const int row, const int col) = 0;
    virtual inline int Size()   const = 0;
    virtual inline int NumOfColumns() const = 0;
    virtual inline int NumOfRows() const = 0;
};


template <class T> 
class CMatrix : public CBaseMatrix
{   
public:

    CMatrix() : 
    m_rawBuff(0),
    m_rawBuffSize(0), 
    m_columns(0), 
    m_rows(0), 
    m_data(0) 
    {};

CMatrix(const CMatrix& matrix):
{
    *this = matrix;
};

    inline int NumOfColumns()   const {return(m_columns);};

    inline int NumOfRows()  const {return(m_rows);};

    inline int Size()   const {return(m_data.size());};

private:
    int m_columns;
    int m_rows;
    vector<T> m_data;
    T*  m_rawBuff ;
    int m_rawBuffSize ;

};
```

I cannot find any problem with the code, and the error itself is not very informative.

I hope that I miss something or that someone encountered a similar problem and has an idea how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your snippet is very inadequate.  What is a "CSegment"?  What is "segments"?

Comment: segments is the argument of the function, I misspelled it, changed it now.
has for CSegment, does it matter what it is?

Comment: Save your code so that you can file a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I found out what the problem was,
notice that in the original code:

```
CMatrix(const CMatrix& matrix):
{
    *this = matrix;
};
```

I have ":" after the constructor, but the initialization list is empty,
Somehow that caused the compiler to crush.

after removing them:

```
CMatrix(const CMatrix& matrix)
{
    *this = matrix;
};
```

everything works!

Note that I submitted the error to Microsoft, and hopefully they will take care of this in the next update, but in the meanwhile, I leave my solution here in case anyone else encounter this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how the code would work under any compiler as:

```
void func(const CMatrix<CSegment>& segment) const
{
    int row, col;
    row = segments.NumOfRows(); //error points to here
    col = segments.NumOfColumns(); 
}
```

Passes in a variable called segment and the code tries to access one called segment**s**.

Try changing the parameter name to segments.

Comment: its my bad, should have said "segments", I fixed it now, must have been deleted in the post without my notice